# Virtual environment not activated in GoCD

Tags: python-3.x, bash, go-cd

I am using GoCD for continuous delivery. I have to deploy python application. For that i created inline bash command. But result is pipeline is failed. This is screen shot of inline command.
[image]
Below screen shot shows the error message in console. How can i solve this issue?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the shell running your pipeline is `bash` ? Have you tried writing 
`. env/bin/activate` instead ?

Comment: Also, please see [this question on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)